# Probability: One die and guess

Tags: probability

1. Imagine that I roll a 6-sided die and record the value, v. Then, I ask you to guess v. After you make your guess, g, I then reveal a hint, h, which is chosen randomly such that h ≠ v and h ≠ g. I then give you the option to keep your original guess or to switch your guess. Should you

a) switch your guess,

b) stay with your original guess,or
c) does it not matter? Explain your reasoning.

To answer this question, let V be a random variable denoting the value of the die. Let H be a random variable denoting the value of the hint. Let G1 be a random variable denoting your original guess and let G2 be a random variable denoting your switched guess.

Compute the following probabilities:

1. For some value h ∈{1,2,3,4,5,6}, compute Pr[H = h]. (Hint: consider
   what happens when g = v and when it doesn’t.)
2. Compute Pr[G1 = V |H = h].
3. Compute Pr[G1 ≠ V |H = h]
4. Compute Pr[G2 = V |H = h]
   Thanks!

---

Here are my answers not sure they are right or not:
    1.P=5/36+20/36=25/36
    2.P=p(G1=v)*p(H=h|G1=v)/p(H=h) = 1/6 * 1/6  / (25/36) = 1/25
    3.P=p(G1≠v)*P(H=h|G1≠v) = 5/6 * 1/6 / (25/36) = 1/5
    4.P=p(G2=v)*P(H=h|G2=v)/P(H=h) = 5/6*1/5 * 1/6 / (25/36) = 1/25

---

try to edit my answer:
1.p = 1/6*5/30+5/6*4/24=1/6
2.P=p(G1=v)*p(H=h|G1=v)/p(H=h) = 1/6 * 1/6  / (1/6)=1/6
3.P=p(G1≠v)*P(H=h|G1≠v) = 5/6 * 1/6 /(1/6) = 5/6
4.
a)  switch your guess,
Pr(G2=v)=P(G2=V)= P(G2=V∣G1=V)P(G1=V)+P(G2=V∣G1≠V)P(G1≠V)=P(G2=V∣G1=V)P(G1=V)+P(G2=V∣G1≠V)P(G1≠V)=0*1/6+1/4*5/6=5/24

b)  stay with your original guess,
Pr(G2=v)=P(G2=V)=1*1/6+0*5/6=1/6
Because 5/24>1/6 so we choose A

Comment: What does h 6=v mean?  This sounds like the [Monty Hall problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monty_Hall_problem).

Comment: Please read firstly [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). And for [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) this post helps.

Comment: What does "h 6 =v" in "which is chosen randomly such that h 6= v and h 6= g." mean??  This is like a puzzle with half of the hints burnt by fire. More details please :)

Comment: @RossMillikan @R zu  Sorry for the mistake, I have edited the question again.

Comment: OK, although != is computerese not math. Your addition is hard to read because the line breaks do not show up.  You need to end a line with two spaces before a line break to make it show.  I don't know why.  In the hint there is reference to H, which is not defined.

Comment: @RossMillikan Thanks for the reminder. I have checked the question and edited it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) By symmetry it follows that all values have equal chance to be elected as hint, so $$P(H=h)=\frac16$$ for every $h\in\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$.

2) By making our first/original guess the probability that our guess is correct is not affected by the hint that we get afterwards, so: $$P(G_1=V\mid H=h)=P(G_1=V)=\frac16$$

3) We can use what we found under 2):$$P(G_1\neq V\mid H=h)=1-P(G_1=V\mid H=h)=1-\frac16=\frac56$$

4) Again the hint given will not affect the probability to guess correctly if we make the switch:$$P(G_2=V\mid H=h)=P(G_2=V)=$$$$P(G_2=V\mid G_1=V)P(G_1=V)+P(G_2=V\mid G_1\neq V)P(G_1\neq V)=$$$$0\cdot\frac16+\frac14\frac56=\frac5{24}$$